# Tikz: Free rotation due to center of gravity

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
  plotmark/.style = {%
    solid, fill = black, circle, inner sep = 0pt, minimum size = 4pt
  },
}

\begin{tikzpicture}

    \coordinate (O) at (0, 0);
    \coordinate (A) at (0, 3);
    \coordinate (G) at (1, 0);
    \node[circle, minimum size=6cm, draw=darkgray] (C) at (O) {};
    \node[plotmark, label={below left:$O$}] at (C.center){};
    \node[plotmark, label={above:$A$}] at (A){};
    \node[plotmark, red] at (G){};

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Suppose G (red dot) is the center of gravity and the object is suspended at a fixed point A and is free to rotate. Without manual calculations, how can I (if possible) rotate the object that point G is vertically below point A?

Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve. Suppose I have:

[image]

Suppose the object is to be suspended from the point F, and suppose point B is the center of gravity. In real life the object will come to:

[image]

Comment: Could you please add a hand-made draw of your desired result? Even a photo of a draw made with a pencil on a sheet of paper is enough.

Comment: @CarLaTex Added an example.

Comment: put them in a `scope` and use `rotate around`  ?

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you could do it in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html).  This might give you a starting point for a TikZ solution.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);

pair A, C, O;
O = origin;
A = 100 up;
C = (42,-13);
path c; c = fullcircle scaled 2 abs(A) shifted O;

picture p[];

p1 = image(
    draw c;
    drawdot O withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
    drawdot A withpen pencircle scaled dotlabeldiam;
    drawdot C withpen pencircle scaled 5/4 dotlabeldiam withcolor 2/3 red;
);

p2 = p1 rotatedabout(A, -90-angle(C-A));
draw p1 withcolor 3/4 white; 
draw p2;

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```